# Form with $_POST is sending empty values to database

Tags: database, wordpress, forms

I've created a form to update several fields from the front-end, but I got **problems with the email and the profile pictures fields**. When I update these fields everything is ok, but then then, when I update the form again the value simply dissapears in the form and in the database.

This is the code with just the two fields and the PHP used (below is the full code):

```
<?php

/* Get user info. */
global $current_user, $wp_roles;
get_currentuserinfo();

/* Load the registration file. */
require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/registration.php' );
$error = array();

/* If profile was saved, update profile. */
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'update-user' ) {

    if ( !empty( $_POST['user-email'] ) ){
        if (!is_email(esc_attr( $_POST['user-email'] )))
            $error[] = __('El email que has introducido no es valido, por favor introduce un correo valido.', 'buscopreparador');
        elseif(email_exists(esc_attr( $_POST['user-email'] )) != $current_user->id )
            $error[] = __('Este email ya esta en uso por otro preparador. intenta utilizando otro.', 'buscopreparador');
        else{
            wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_email' => esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )));
        }
    }


    /* Update ACF Fields */
    $user_id_acf = 'user_'.$current_user->ID;

    if( !empty( $_FILES['imagen-perfil'] ) ) {

        /* Function to pass the image to the media and database */
        $att = my_update_attachment('imagen-perfil', $user_id_acf);
        update_field('field_56ea616d98e27', $att['attach_id'], $user_id_acf);
    }


    /* Redirect so the page will show updated info.*/
    /*I am not Author of this Code- i dont know why but it worked for me after changing below line to if ( count($error) == 0 ){ */
    if ( count($error) == 0 ) {
        do_action('personal_options_update', $current_user->ID);
        wp_redirect( get_permalink().'?updated=true' ); exit;
    }       
}

get_header(); ?>


<form method="post" id="adduser" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">


        <!-- Email -->
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="user-email"><?php _e('Email', 'buscopreparador'); ?></label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="user-email" id="user-email" placeholder="danielmartinez@gmail.com" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'user_email', $current_user->ID ); ?>">
        </div>

        <!-- Imagen de Perfil -->
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="imagen-perfil">Imagen de Perfil</label>
            <input type="file" name="imagen-perfil" id="imagen-perfil">
            <p class="help-block">Selecciona tu imagen de perfil, esta debe tener entre 200x200 y 400x400 pixeles.</p>
        </div>


    </div>

    <p class="form-submit">
        <?php echo $referer; ?>
        <input name="updateuser" type="submit" id="updateuser" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" value="<?php _e('Actualizar', 'buscopreparador'); ?>">
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'update-user_'. $current_user->ID ) ?>
        <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="update-user" />
    </p><!-- .form-submit -->

</form><!-- #adduser -->
```

This is my code to update the database fields:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: User Profile
 *
 * Allow users to update their profiles from Frontend.
 */

/* Get user info. */
global $current_user, $wp_roles;
get_currentuserinfo();

/* Load the registration file. */
require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/registration.php' );
$error = array();

/* If profile was saved, update profile. */
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'update-user' ) {

    /* Update user password. */
    if ( !empty($_POST['user-password1'] ) && !empty( $_POST['user-password2'] ) ) {
        if ( $_POST['user-password1'] == $_POST['user-password2'] )
            wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_pass' => esc_attr( $_POST['user-password1'] ) ) );
        else
            $error[] = __('Las contraseñas que has introducido no concuerdan.  No se ha actualizado su contraseña.', 'buscopreparador');
    }

    /* Update user website. */
    if ( !empty( $_POST['user-web'] ) )
       wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_url' => esc_attr( $_POST['user-web'] )));

    if ( !empty( $_POST['user-email'] ) ){
        if (!is_email(esc_attr( $_POST['user-email'] )))
            $error[] = __('The Email you entered is not valid.  please try again.', 'buscopreparador');
        elseif(email_exists(esc_attr( $_POST['user-email'] )) != $current_user->id )
            $error[] = __('Este email ya esta en uso por otro preparador. intenta utilizando otro.', 'buscopreparador');
        else{
            wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $current_user->ID, 'user_email' => esc_attr( $_POST['email'] )));
        }
    }


    if ( !empty( $_POST['first-name'] ) )
        update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'first_name', esc_attr( $_POST['first-name'] ) );
    if ( !empty( $_POST['last-name'] ) )
        update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'last_name', esc_attr( $_POST['last-name'] ) );
    if ( !empty( $_POST['nickname'] ) )
        update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'nickname' , esc_attr( $_POST['nickname'] ));

    /* Update ACF Fields */
    $user_id_acf = 'user_'.$current_user->ID;

    if( !empty( $_POST['titulacion-preparador'] ) )
        update_field( 'field_56e6c502df6af', esc_attr( $_POST['titulacion-preparador'] ), $user_id_acf );

    if( !empty( $_POST['descripcion-breve'] ) )
        update_field( 'field_56e6c622df6b2', esc_textarea( $_POST['descripcion-breve'] ), $user_id_acf );

    if( !empty( $_POST['materiales-disponibles'] ) )
        update_field( 'field_56e939f3d2671', esc_textarea( $_POST['materiales-disponibles'] ), $user_id_acf );

    if( !empty( $_FILES['imagen-perfil'] ) ) {
        $att = my_update_attachment('imagen-perfil', $user_id_acf);
        update_field('field_56ea616d98e27', $att['attach_id'], $user_id_acf);
    }


    /* Redirect so the page will show updated info.*/
    /*I am not Author of this Code- i dont know why but it worked for me after changing below line to if ( count($error) == 0 ){ */
    if ( count($error) == 0 ) {

        do_action('personal_options_update', $current_user->ID);
        wp_redirect( get_permalink().'?updated=true' ); exit;
    }       
}
```

This is the form code:

```
<form method="post" id="adduser" action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Nombre -->
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="first-name"><?php _e('Nombre', 'buscopreparador'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first-name" id="first-name" placeholder="Daniel" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'first_name', $current_user->ID ); ?>">
        </div>

        <!-- Apellido -->
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="last-name"><?php _e('Apellidos', 'buscopreparador'); ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last-name" id="last-name" placeholder="Martinez Martinez" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'last_name', $current_user->ID ); ?>">
        </div>

        <!-- Alias Público -->
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="alias-publico"><?php _e('Alias Público', 'buscopreparador') ?></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nickname" id="nickname" placeholder="Daniel Martinez" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'nickname', $current_user->ID ); ?>">
        </div>

        <!-- Email -->
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="user-email"><?php _e('Email', 'buscopreparador'); ?></label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="user-email" id="user-email" placeholder="danielmartinez@gmail.com" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'user_email', $current_user->ID ); ?>">
        </div>

        <!-- Web -->
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="user-web"><?php _e('Web', 'buscopreparador'); ?></label>
            <input type="url" class="form-control" name="user-web" id="user-web" value="<?php the_author_meta( 'user_url', $current_user->ID ); ?>" placeholder="http://www.miweb.com">
        </div>

        <!-- Imagen de Perfil -->
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="imagen-perfil">Imagen de Perfil</label>
            <input type="file" name="imagen-perfil" id="imagen-perfil">
            <p class="help-block">Selecciona tu imagen de perfil, esta debe tener entre 200x200 y 400x400 pixeles.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- Password-1 -->
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="user-password1"><?php _e('Contraseña', 'buscopreparador'); ?></label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="user-password1" id="user-password1">
        </div>

        <!-- Password-2 -->
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="user-password2"><?php _e('Repite la Contraseña', 'buscopreparador'); ?></label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="user-password2" id="user-password2">
        </div>                                      

    </div>

    <p class="form-submit">
        <?php echo $referer; ?>
        <input name="updateuser" type="submit" id="updateuser" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" value="<?php _e('Actualizar', 'profile'); ?>">
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'update-user_'. $current_user->ID ) ?>
        <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="update-user" />
    </p><!-- .form-submit -->

</form><!-- #adduser -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid sending an empty image I'm using:

```
if( !empty( $_FILES['imagen-perfil']['size'] > 0 ) ) {
```

The **['size'] > 0** seems to work, but, I don't know why. Couldn't solve the email problem yet.